# Can I run output of Python code/text file in Julia?

Tags: julia

I wrote a python script that generates a tree and outputs some variable creation and function calls in Julia syntax to a text file (I am testing the correctness of some Julia tree algorithms in phylogenetics).
I was wondering if there is a way to "run" the text file in a Julia Jupyter notebook?
It gets tedious to manually copy the file and run it as I am generating many files.

Comment: Does typing `include("filename.jl")` in a cell work for your needs?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! Don't know how I didn't find that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `include("treealgos.jl")` in a Jupyter cell, to run the entire file there. It's equivalent to copy-pasting the file contents to that cell, and all the variables and functions defined in the file become available in the notebook after that.

Note that this is very different from `using` or `import`ing a module, which require a `module` name and come with extra features like namespacing and `export`s. An `include` in contrast is a more basic and simpler feature, similar to a `#include` in C language, just bringing the code that was `include`d into wherever the `include` statement happens to be.

Comment: *(bringing my response from the question comments and expanding on it, since this appears as an "Unanswered question")*